# Rails custom foreign_key name on both table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

I have two models, for example User and Club with their attributes:

```
User:
  id
  uid
  email
  etc.
```

and

```
Club:
  id
  player_id
  address
  supporter
  etc.
```

For some reason, the join attribute is `clubs.player_id` with `users.uid` NOT `clubs.player_id` with `users.id`. Is it possible connecting these two model with `one-to-one` association using `has_one` and `belongs_to`? thx

Comment: A few years late to the party but this post is still relevant! Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I bet this would work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :club, :foreign_key => :player_id, :primary_key => :uid
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :player_id, :primary_key => :uid
end
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: we don't need to specify the foreign key and primary key in the User's model, only the Club model should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Can Clubs have many Users and Users belong to many Clubs?  If so, you may want to look at the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html page for the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship association method. If you use this association method, you will need to create a separate migration table to relate the user_id with the club_id.

Comment: FYI, you cannot use `:primary_key` for `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, so if you require that, you'll *need* to use a `has_many :through` relationship.