# How do I create custom foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am building a Ruby on Rails application that will have data dumped into my PostgreSQL installation pretty regularly. Right now I have two entities, Accounts and Addresses.

Accounts has many Addresses. As of now the foreign key relationship is setup as Rails defaults it, where Addresses has a column called `account_id`. However Rails is never going to create the data, it is just going to read it. My external service that is dumping data creates a unique ID called `masterID` onto my account records, and places that ID into the `associatedID` column of the associated addresses.

I need Rails to use the `masterID` field and `associatedID` field when looking for associated addresses.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :address , :foreign_key => 'masterID'
    end
```

Read "[Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)" for more information under section 4.1.2.5.

Comment: Instead of saying `Read "here"`, use some real text that lets the reader know what they're clicking on. See "[Don't use 'click here' as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" and "[6.1 Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" for more information.

Comment: so now when I do that, is it going to use master ID on account, but is it going to store that key on the address  table in associatedID column?

Comment: in that case you need to add :primary_key=> 'associatedID'

Comment: wait, will that really do that? A isn't a primary key different?

Comment: you define overriding foreign keys and primary keys in the model. not in the migration file.

Comment: So then really the primary key is being defined on the account and the forign key is bing defined on the address?

Comment: yes it depends on how you want to store it but you define them in the models so for every method they are used. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640941/rails-custom-foreign-key-name-on-both-table

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify `foreign_keys` when you declare your `has_many` association:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, foreign_key: 'masterID'
end
```

There is more info in the [`has_many` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) (check out the options).