# Rails add foreign key on non-primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

In Rails 5.1 I have the following relations:

```
class RootArea < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :common_areas
end

class CommonArea < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :root_area, foreign_key: 'area_id', optional: true
end
```

and below are their migrations:

```
create_table "root_areas", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "area_id"
  t.string "localname"
  t.string "globalname"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "common_areas", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "area_id"
  t.string "localname"
  t.string "globalname"
  t.integer :root_area_id
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

My goal is to "connect" `common_areas` to `root_areas` -**on `area_id` instead of just the `id`**- so that a single root area entry may "have" multiple common areas.

For instance USA(`RootArea`) has California(`CommonArea`), Texas(`CommonArea`) etc.

I tried to do this using a migration and a foreign key as shown below:

```
add_foreign_key :common_areas, :root_areas, primary_key: :area_id
```

and while at first this seemed to work well, it eventually failed:

```
>>> RootArea.create!(area_id: 1111, 
                     localname: ’test', 
                     globalname: ’test') # OK

>>> CommonArea.create!(area_id: 9999, 
                       localname: ’test', 
                       globalname: ’test') # OK

>>> RootArea.first.common_areas << CommonArea.first # Error

=> # SQL (44.3ms)  UPDATE "common_areas" SET "root_area_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "common_areas"."id" = $3  [["root_area_id", 19], ["updated_at", "2018-02-20 14:45:52.545450"], ["id", 1]]
```

The output suggests that Rails tries to set `CommonArea`'s attribute `root_area_id` as `RootArea`'s primary key (`id` instead of `area_id`).

For instance in the above example the generated sql statement should have set `root_area_id` to `1111` instead of `19`.

Comment: Could you please share your classes and relations?

Comment: Updated. rwoldd

Comment: Thanks. So you've no class called 'area'? It looks as if it would be an easier way to achieve what you want using `has_many ... through `

Comment: I don't quite understand why there are both `root_areas` and `common_areas` tables. Or why this isn't a HMT etc.

Comment: So, I'm trying to do the following: i.e. California `belongs_to` USA, Texas `belongs_to` USA etc. But I also need to be able to do USA.common_areas and spit out California, Texas etc. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Later this evening I seeked out some further help from the Rails IRC channel and eventually user `dionysus69` pointed me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640941/rails-custom-foreign-key-name-on-both-table) which was very similar to what I was looking for. For future reference this is the final solution:

```
class RootArea < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :common_areas, foreign_key: 'root_area_id', primary_key: 'area_id'
end

class CommonArea < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :root_area, foreign_key: 'root_area_id', primary_key: 'area_id', optional: true
end
```

Now I can successfully do

```
>>  RootArea.first.common_areas << CommonArea.first
```

and have `root_area_id` set to the proper `area_id` value instead of the `id`.